# Finding length of edges of an Object via image processing

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to find length of each edge of an object in an image using machine vision. So far, I'm able to get length of whole object but not able to find length of particular length. Here is the code I'm using and the input/output,

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("IMAGE PATH")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
# cnts = [x for x in cnts if cv2.contourArea(x) > 500]


(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
pixelsPerMetric = None

for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
        continue

    orig = image.copy()
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")


    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # loop over the original points and draw them
    for (x, y) in box:
        cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)


    ################################LOGIC FOR CALCULATING LENGHT FROM PIXELS########################
```

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: Get the contours. Then limit the number of vertices using approxPolyDP(). Once you  have just the vertices that define the object, you can compute the distances (lengths) from vertex to vertex.

Comment: Did you mean "to find length of particular edge"?